# "on form submit" trigger on response spreadsheet stopped working with google change

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms, google-sheets-api

I have a google form with a response spreadsheet and code (on the sheet) that is associated with an "on form submit" trigger.  This has been working without issue for years.  Google's recent change to the security/Oauth seems to have broken it.  It does not appear that the code is even firing when the form is submitted.  Has anyone else experienced this since google's latest changes?  I was asked to reauthorize and I typed "continue" to do so and I can execute the code manually, but the triggers appear not to work.

Comment: You may want to check the Issue Tracker [Link to Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open) and post to the Apps Script community:  [Link to Apps Script community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: I've seen similar in the past.  Have you tried deleting & recreating the trigger?

Comment: I think you might  be  able to go to [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard) and see some errors in  the error reporting section.